# problems when writing document () of own package

Tags: r

I am trying to build my own package with Rstudio, and I have problems with the documentation. 
             devtools::document()

I got the following error:

```
         Updating jcext documentation
         Loading jcext
         Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
```

I am a bit lost,and not sure where the error could be (maybe I'm missing something in the NAMESPACE or DESCRIPTION...any idea?

My NAMESPACE was created and looks like:

```
      # Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

        export(AddDate)
        export(CalculateCWT)
        export(CalculateConstant)
```

Any suggestion will help,

Comment: Is your code on github?

Comment: Hi!, no the code it's not yet there, but I think I know where the problem was ; I realised I had some @param  empty in one function. I just filled it, build & reload again and it seems that it is now working.